# Resize div to top center of the page with respect to window when window increases or decreases in its width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing problem in fixing CSS, I have one div, I need to adjust div with respect to `window width` when it increase or decrease, the div must be at `top center` of the page. I tried like

```
<div style="display:table;margin:0 auto"></div>
```

But this will not fit to center when window width increase.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.... Yout markup and CSS

Comment: I have this div <div style="overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;width:100%">  for the <form> and inside this <div1 style="display:table;margin:0 auto"> ..i have to adjust div1

Comment: Add your markup and css in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CSS like following,

```
div {
width:70%; // set width in '%' to adjust with respect to window.
margin:0 auto; // to centerlize div.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
     <div style="display:inline-block;margin:0 auto;background:red;">mydiv</div>
    </div>
```